# Typedef char pointer allocation of string

Tags: c, string, pointers, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am trying to understand a code that has the `typedef char *` I am supposed to allocate memory enough for the  string `"Pointer of"` and `"Redundancy"`.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef char* DString;
DString dstring_initialize(const char* str);

int main(void)
{
    DString str1, str2;
    str1 = dstring_initialize("Pointer of ");
    str2 = dstring_initialize("Redundancy ");
return 0;
}

DString dstring_initialize(const char* str)
{
  str = malloc((strlen(str)+1)*sizeof(DString));//mycode 
  return str;//mycode
}
```

I am 100% sure that I am doing it completely wrong. The only thing I am supposed to do is change the part where it says `mycode`. It was sent to me like that, but as I said before, I don't know how it works, and if someone could explain it to me in detail, I would appreciate it

Comment: `str = malloc((strlen(str)+1)*sizeof *str);` (and this method works for *any* type)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the code below you allocate too much memory:

```
str = malloc((strlen(str)+1)*sizeof(DString));//mycode 
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                             Not needed
```

Also you assign the return value from `malloc` to the input argument, i.e. you "destroy" the input.

Further, you never copy the value of the input string to the allocated memory.

Instead of the above, you need:

```
char* res = malloc(strlen(str) + 1);
if (res != NULL)
{
    strcpy(res, str);
}
return res;
```

Comment: Let's put it this way:  this site is a ***lot*** more forgiving than your compiler.

Answer (score 1):

There are two areas of memory, the stack where local things exist, and the heap where other things exist. The stack is automatic in that your compiler manages it for you, and the heap is something that you have to manage through calls to `malloc`, `realloc`, and `free`, etc.

Things that are known at compile can exist in the stack, whereas things that you don't know at compile time can exist in the heap and be allocated, reallocated, freed, etc., with calls to `malloc`, `realloc`, and `free`.

And that basically all comes down to the size of the memory allocated. If you declare, for example, an int, that int can change in value as your program executes because it always exists in a space that is the `sizeof` an int.

But you might want to place your string in the heap if it changes length while the program runs and you don't want to allocate something big enough to always be able to hold it. For example, you don't need to allocate space on the heap for `str` if you always made it big enough with something like `char str[64]` or something like that because you allocate that space ahead of time.

In terms of `malloc`, you ask it to allocate memory of a certain size, and if it can it returns a pointer to it, if it can't it returns `NULL`. So the variable that holds the pointer returned by `malloc` exists in the stack, and the memory allocated by `malloc` exists in the heap and is not automatic. Ie: when your program terminates the pointer variable in the stack is released but not the actual memory stored in the heap, so you have to free it with `free`.

In the case of `sizeof`, well, that tells malloc how much you want to allocate, in this case a `char`, but it can be *anything* that can be resolved to a size, for example a structure that you define, etc. So what you're basically saying when you call `malloc` is "give me something this big and give me this many of them". In this case, "give me something as big as a char" and give me "`strlen(str) + 1` of them".

And because the size of a character is always 1 byte and `strlen` returns a value of type `size_t` which `malloc` takes you can simply do it as `char *ptr = malloc(strlen(str) + 1)`. But keep in mind that `malloc` returns a pointer of type `void` so you need to cast it to the type you are requesting. In this case you would cast it to a `char*` like this: `ptr = (char*)malloc(strlen(str) + 1)`.

The other error is described in the other answer. But that is basically in a nutshell how `malloc` works. I'm not a teacher and I apologize if I'm not 100% clear.